# Understanding UCD-DISKIO-MIB object - diskIONWritten Column

Tags: snmp, mib

I'm using ucdDiskIOMIB MIB object to get disk IO.

Everything works fine but I don't understand counter data I'm getting.
Im querying diskIONWritten columns and result is constantly increasing until one moment when it decrease.

Here is example of my results for better understanding.
Data is queried every 3 seconds and looks like this.

First run:

```
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.1] => Counter32: 0
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.2] => Counter32: 4059038720
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.3] => Counter32: 9216
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.4] => Counter32: 10907648
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.5] => Counter32: 4048121856
```

Second run: (increase)

```
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.1] => Counter32: 0
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.2] => Counter32: 4188124160
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.3] => Counter32: 9216
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.4] => Counter32: 10907648
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.5] => Counter32: 4177207296
```

Third run: (decrease)

```
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.1] => Counter32: 0
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.2] => Counter32: 31888384
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.3] => Counter32: 9216
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.4] => Counter32: 10907648
[UCD-DISKIO-MIB::diskIONWritten.5] => Counter32: 20971520
```

On net-snmp I read this description for diskIOWritten tale column:
"The number of bytes written to this device since boot".
And I'm expecting result to increase on each query (until system reboot).

Do anybody know what I'm missing here?

Thanks in advice

Comment: Hi, I think what you're missing is a programming question. Please post this question on serverfault.com instead, as this seems to be about management of network equipment, not programming.

Comment: From the MIB document itself, http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/UCD-DISKIO-MIB.txt it indicates that only net-snmp guys know. I personally assume that you should read the source code so as to find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter32 is a 32 bit unsigned integer, the maximum value is 4294967295. It looks like your values became too big and overflowed. Basically if the counter exceeds 4294967295 it will reset to 0.

Comment: I was guessing the same, just wanted to hear other opinions. Thanks!